# Why does the period in the classList.() function work with some and not with others?

Tags: javascript, function

So I am trying to add classes to javascript and I put showMenu.classList.toggle('.open') with the period after open and the click events work. Meanwhile I put the period after class on my other functions and one works when I put in on the other and the then the other one shuts down. Can anyone explain to me what is happening? Here's my code:

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.toggler');
const showMenu = document.querySelector('.showmenu');
const links = document.querySelector('.showlink');
const showLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.showlinks > li');



menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showMenu.classList.toggle('.open');
    console.log(showMenu.classList.toggle('open'))
    links.classList.toggle('.open');
    showLinks.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('open'));
    console.log(showLinks);
});
```

Comment: Which line doesn't work?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi So I put a period on the links toggle and then the show links don't work and vice versa. It could be because they are ul and li elements.

Comment: Are you confusing `.querySelectorAll` and `.querySelector` with `.classList.toggle`? That's my guess. `.querySelectorAll` and `.querySelector` take CSS selectors, including the class selector like `.showLinks`, while `.classList.toggle` takes a className with no `.`. So, it should be like `showMenu.classList.toggle('open');`.

Comment: Hi, @StackSlave. I think I was messing up by console.logging the toggle method and it was messing everything up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the class without the dot, so just `showMenu.classList.toggle('open')`, so your code should look something like this:

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.toggler');
const showMenu = document.querySelector('.showmenu');
const links = document.querySelector('.showlink');
const showLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.showlinks > li');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  showMenu.classList.toggle('open');
  links.classList.toggle('open');

  console.log(showMenu.classList);
  console.log(links.classList);

  showLinks.forEach(item => {
    item.classList.toggle('open');

    console.log(item.classList);
  });
});
```

Comment: hi @danziger. I tried that but when I did the click event didn't work but it works with the period.

Comment: In `document.querySelector()` you use the dot because you are indicating that's a class selector (it could also be an element selector, an id selector...) but `classList.toggle()` goes without the dot because you are only passing a class name, not a selector. Check the example above, I also think you didn't really want to call `toggle()` inside `console.log()`.

Comment: Thanks@ Danziger, i think that was the problem. I was calling it inside a console.log and it was screwing everything up. I was just trying to see the output to learn what was happening behind the scenes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alanaj Happy to help (: Would be great if you can then accept/upvote the answer.